# C++ Can't Print Values from Array of Strings

Tags: c++, windows

I am having trouble with an assignment for my freshman Computer Science class.
I am trying to have PrintAllConcepts print each item of an array, once per line.

For some reason all I get is the last line printed from LIST.txt and a bunch of extra empty lines that usually end up nearly crashing the program. There appears to be no syntactical errors, so I'm afraid I am not reading the concepts into the array correctly. This is where I would like assistance.
Below is my code.

I also apologize if this seems like a noob question, as I am a beginner in C++.
Edit: Also, explaining why the Number parameter is so funky, my assignment seems to be requiring me to do it that way. That is also why PrintAllConcepts and ReadConcepts returns void.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

void ReadConcepts(std::string Concepts[100], int &Number) {
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("LIST.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
    }
    std::string theConcepts[100];
    std::string line;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
        while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
            theConcepts[i] = line;
            Number++;
        }
    }
}

void PrintAllConcepts(std::string Concepts[100], int Number) {
    int i;
    std::string line;
    for (i = 0; i < Number - 1; i++) {
        line = Concepts[i];
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << i;
}

int main() {
    // Initiate variables
    std::string Concepts[100];
    int Number = 100;
    // Read concepts
    ReadConcepts(Concepts, Number);

    // Open file for void function PrintAllConcepts
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("LIST.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
    }
    int i;
    std::string line;
    for (i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
            Concepts[i] = line;
        }
    }
    PrintAllConcepts(Concepts, Number);

}
```

Comment: Please learn how to *debug* your programs. Some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should show problems with the `ReadConcepts` function. Or use a debugger to step through the function statement by statement to see exactly what happens.

Comment: And think about the two arrays `Concepts` and `theConcepts`. Which are you reading into? Which will be printed later?

Comment: You also need to think about the `Number` variables, how it's initialized, incremented and used.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so the issue is with ReadConcepts rather than PrintAllConcepts? I am not very familiar with debugging in the code itself yet, but the debugger in Visual Studio compiles and runs the code without issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you commented, the error**s** are in the `ReadConcepts` function.

To begin with you should *not* increment `Number` in the loop, as it's already the number of elements in the array. Because you increment `Number` you will pass the value `200` to `PrintAllConcepts` which will make it go out of bounds of the array.

Secondly you put all strings into the *local* array `theConcepts` instead of the array `Concepts` passed to the function. This means none of the strings in `Concepts` will be set, giving you the "empty" output. Remove the `theConcepts` array and use `Concepts` instead.

Thirdly you should have *either* the `for` loop, *or* the `while` loop, but not both. Since you have both the first iteration of the `for` loop will read *all* lines from the file, putting all of it into `theConcepts[0]`, and leave the rest of the array with empty strings. I recommend a *combination* of both loops, as in:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Number && std::getline(fin, line); ++i)
{
    Concepts[i] = line;
}
```

---

There are also some other "problem" that aren't serious and won't cause any errors. One of them is passing the `Number` argument by reference. Since `Number` should not be modified you should pass it by value.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. They were very helpful. God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

As a perfunctory node to your question, you may want to insert a condition for reading the file in its entirety, i.e., while (fin.good()), etc.

That said, the above hints and tips are second to none.  Debugging programs can teach you a lot, and are as good a learning tool as writing the code yourself.  I should know; I'm new at this too.  Good luck.

p.s.: Don't forget the good practice of closing your file once finished with it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure to close up my files after they're done, and work on my debugging skills.